# Can you concatenate two multi-index objects in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I haven't been able to find any documentation about how to concatenate two MultiIndex objects, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Bit late but maybe useful for someone else:

I don't think `concat` works with index objects but you can use `append`.

For example:

```
idx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([keys_1, keys_2])
idx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([keys_3, keys_4])

print(idx1)
MultiIndex([(  'one',  'two'),
            (  'one',  'two'),
            (  'one', 'two')],
           )

print(idx2)
MultiIndex([(  'three',  'four'),
            (  'three',  'four'),
            (  'three', 'four')],
           )

new_idx = idx1.append(idx2)

print(new_idx )
MultiIndex([(  'one',  'two'),
            (  'one',  'two'),
            (  'one',  'two'),
            (  'three',  'four'),
            (  'three',  'four'),
            (  'three', 'four')],
           )
```